# PowerShell PSDefaultParamterValues

Tags: powershell

I came across this private error variable example recently.

```
#hiding errors:
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
#telling all cmdlets to use a private variable for error logging:
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add('*:ErrorVariable', '+myErrors')
#initializing the variable:
$myErrors = $null

#do stuff:
Stop-Service -Name Spooler
dir c:\gibtsnichtabcs

#check errors at end USING PRIVATE VARIABLE:
$myErrors
```

I just want to understand the **$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add** line above as to how prepending **+** to the **myErrors** variable name makes it cumulative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `$PSDefaultParameterValues` line causes PowerShell to pass argument `-ErrorVariable +myErrors` to all cmdlets or *advanced* functions.

The [documentation for the -ErrorVariable common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2#-errorvariable) says:

> By default, new error messages overwrite error messages that are
> already stored in the variable. To append the error message to the
> variable content, type a plus sign (+) before the variable name.

So the "cumulative" behaviour is implemented in PowerShell's handling of the common parameters.